# How to properly wait listener with Coroutine in Android

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I use **Callback** pattern as a reaction of ClickListener, but I'm trying to use ***Coroutine*** at the moment.
Sometimes, so much of overlap of callback is hell.

When I click a item of RecyclerView, I want to know that position of item I clicked.

I made it with **Channel** and it works.

*MainActivity.class*

```
class MainActivity: Activity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityYoutubeFakeHomeBinding
private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityYoutubeFakeHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setView()
}

private fun setView() = scope.launch {

    val positionChannel = Channel<Int>(Channel.UNLIMITED)
    myAdapter = MyAdapter(this@MainActivity, positionChannel)

    launch {
        while(true) {
            dialogUtil.showEdit(positionChannel.receive())
        }
    }

    binding.run {
        recyclerView.apply {
            adapter = myAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        }
    }
}
```

}

*MyAdapter.class*

```
class MyAdapter(private val context: Context,
                          private val channel: Channel<Int>): RecyclerView.Adapter< MyAdapter.HomeViewHolder>() {

private val fakeHomeList = mutableListOf<FakeVideo>()

inner class HomeViewHolder(private val binding: ItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(fakeVideo: FakeVideo) {
        binding.run {
            thumbnailImageView.setImageBitmap(fakeVideo.thumbnail)
            titleTextView.text = fakeVideo.title
           
            root.setOnClickListener {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                    channel.send(adapterPosition)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeViewHolder {
    val binding = ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return HomeViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(fakeHomeList[position])
}

override fun getItemCount() = fakeHomeList.size
```

}

Yeah, it works.  But I'm not sure whether this is the proper way.

Is there any better solution with ***Coroutine*** maybe like suspend function something?

Comment: @Raghunandan  I know that Callback pattern. But now I'm trying to use Coroutine without callback.  Anyway Thanks.

Comment: I think callback is not very painful here. the good point of kotlin is that you can pass lambdas without creating a new interface, just like what you should do in java. so just pass a lambda like val onClick: () -> Unit to your adapter's constructor. then call onClick.invoke() when your adapter item is clicked.

Comment: @Reza haha I know the Kotlin lamda callback pattern is really convenient. But If there is some situation that more than 4 callbacks are overwritten, the code will be dirty. So I'm studying Coroutine, I wanna replace callback with Coroutine something...  I just wanna utilize Coroutine.  Anyway Thank u!

Comment: @J.Dragon but for such a simple task you don't need to use channels. see the android dev blog on medium https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/for-my-next-trick-i-will-write-about-onclick-45e0a6881c8a.